# How do I get two different Django projects to communicate?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

Like the title says, I have two Django projects. Unlike other SO questions, these are totally different projects, meaning they do not share database, hosting environment, domain name, etc. This is what I want and need, total decoupling between the projects.

However, they have certain models (let's say UserProfile) from one app which I required in both projects. Also, I would like to have only one of the projects to allow sign-in, log-in, forgot/reset password functionality.

My idea is to have RESTful APIs for both of them, but I still have some questions about how to correctly achieve this:

- what do I do with the duplicate models to keep them in-sync? Do I create endpoints which can be modified by the other project?
- how do I proceed with single-sign-on ? Do I need a specialised server for this? I would also like to take advantage of the tools provided by Django, such as having my current user on my request object.

I have yet to find a good tutorial or some detailed explanations as to how to achieve all of these, so if anyone has any resources, please let me know.

If my question is not clear enough, please let me know with a comment.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need the models to be in sync immediately, in real time, or is some delay acceptable?

Comment: Delay is acceptable, as long as there is a not too long period of time (couple of minutes) which allows to say they are in sync with a high degree of certainty.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you require the UserProfile model in both of them, and if you are not sharing the databases, then you are putting redundant data in your database i.e., same data in both database d1 and d2.

The only possible solution I could think of is have two separate databases d1 and d2 accessible by both. So this way, even if changes take place in say d1 using app1, then also you can detect these change in app2 and hence the same goes for app1 detecting changes of d2 as well.

This way when your user logs in app1, changes take place in d1 which is also read by app2 and hence app2 doesn't requires user authentication separately.

See this -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/

And this too -> [Can I have two django projects sharing the same authentication model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699247/can-i-have-two-django-projects-sharing-the-same-authentication-model)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, but maybe I wasn't clear enough. I want total decoupling, so allowing one project to read the database of the other project is not an option :( Redundancy is indeed the way to go, but I would like to solve consistency problems at an API level, not at database level. I need this abstraction in order to reuse any of my projects.

Comment: What do you mean by 'reuse'? Can you give an example where you would reuse a project?

Comment: For example, if I ever need to replace one of the projects, so that project A no longer uses the API from project B to communicate, but a new project - project C let's say, which is written in another language.

Comment: It is unclear to me what your goals are and why you need data redundancy. If you ever needed to replace a project and rewrite in another language, a one database solution would work for that. But you could always write background scripts to keep the databases in sync if you'd like. You could have the model keep track of its changes so that you only sync over the latest updates. There will be some delay but this sounds acceptable for you. I am less familiar with sso but I can help with any data syncing questions, feel free to comment if you have any.